# Compound verb in a "would you like to" question

Tags: verbs, questions

If I have a "would you like to _____" question, which words in that question are considered to be part of the compound verb?

For example, if I have this question:

> Would you like to eat ice-cream or to drink a milkshake?

Which words in this question are considered to be part of the compound verb?

Comment: I think you mean a coordination of clauses. In "Would you like [to eat ice-cream] or [to drink a milkshake]", the bracketed items form a coordination of two non-finite subordinate clauses, each functioning as complement of "like".

Comment: The main verb phrase is "would like."

Comment: have some ice cream or a milk shake is more idiomatic  here.

Answer (score 1):

The general principle of parallelism applies here.

> Would you like to eat ice cream or drink a milkshake?

Could be expanded to

> Would you like to eat ice cream or would you like to drink a milkshake?

If there are more parts that are repeated, then only the parts that differ need to be said.

> Would you like to drink a milkshake or a coke?  *(drink is factored out) *
>
> Would you like to drink a raspberry milkshake or smoothie *(both are raspberry flavour)*
>
> Would Mary or Sammy like to eat ice cream *(would Mary like to...or would Sammy like to...)